# Django home page URL being rendered as a different URL

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-urls

So, I have a simple home page for a django project I am working on. In the upper left hand corner is the logo for the site. In my template, I have this code:

`<a href="{% url "home" %}">Company Name</a>`

In my root urls.py, I have this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),          # The main app
   url(r'^login/$', include('app.urls')),     # The login page
)
```

and in my app/urls.py I have this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),             # The homepage of the website
      url(r'^login/$', views.loginView, name='login'),  # The login page of the website
)
```

Now you would think (or at least I would) that when the index page is rendered, it would generate the html `<a href="/">Company Name</a>` or something similar. Instead, what I get is `<a href="/login/">Company Name</a>`.

So, why happen? Obviously, this is unwanted behavior. I am almost certain the issue is in the url configuration, but I could be wrong.

Please and thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the same URLpatterns twice. Your main urls.py should just be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'', include('app.urls')),
)
```

Then your URLs will resolve/reverse as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are including the same file `app.urls` *under two relative paths*, namely `/` and `/login`. So, the *right* url name definition is just overwritten.

To avoid this, do not include the same url config file under two relative paths. So, in your case, you should create a new url config file (say `login.urls`), move login related url definitions to that new file and replace the root url config with

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),          # The main app
    url(r'^login/$', include('login.urls')),     # The login page
)
```